# How to specify the coordinates x and y in a path tag svg?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a svg who represents some containers and I want to add dynamically with JavaScript a cross in each container.

I have this code to add a cross in the container:

```css
.close-x {
  stroke: black;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentscripttype="application/ecmascript" contentstyletype="text/css" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1181px;height:555px;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="f491e1k" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"></feGaussianBlur><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"></feColorMatrix><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"></feOffset><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"></feBlend></filter></defs>
<g>
<!--entity cadvisor-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="97" x="133.675" y="8"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="210.675" y="13"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="15"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="19"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="148.675" y="41.3027">cadvisor</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 140,12 L 150,25 M 150,12 L 140,25"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

but it's static and I want to make it dynamically.

With JavaScript I can get the position of the `<text>` (I can't provide a fiddle because it never works I don't know why but in my JS it works)

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].childNodes[1].childNodes;
    console.log(list)

      for (var x in list) {
        if (list.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
          if(list[x].tagName === "text"){
            console.log("-----------------");
            console.log(list[x]);
            console.log("y: ");
            console.log(list[x].y.baseVal[0].valueAsString);
            console.log("x: ")
            console.log(list[x].x.baseVal[0].valueAsString);

            //<path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />

          }
        }
      }
```

But if I try to do `<path class="close-x" y="81" x="125"></path>` I doesn't show the cross...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution founded with the help of @Peter Collingridge

```js
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(){
  var textEl = document.getElementsByTagName('text')[0];

  var x = parseFloat(textEl.getAttribute('x')) - 8;
  var y = parseFloat(textEl.getAttribute('y')) - 29;
 $(textEl).after("<path class='close-x' transform='translate("+x +"," + y +")' d='M 0,0 l10,13 M 10,0 l-10 13'></path>");
 
  var myHtml = $("#b").html();
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = myHtml;
}
```

```css
.close-x {
  stroke: black;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

rect {
  fill: #FEFECE;
  stroke: #A80036;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a">click</button>
<div id="b">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="f491e1k" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"></feGaussianBlur><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"></feColorMatrix><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"></feOffset><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"></feBlend></filter></defs>
<g id="messageBox" >
<!--entity cadvisor-->
<rect filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" width="97" x="100" y="0"></rect>
<rect height="10" width="15" x="177" y="5"></rect>
<rect height="2" width="4" x="175" y="7"></rect>
<rect height="2" width="4" x="175" y="11"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="115" y="33.3027">cadvisor</text>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `path` element to show up it needs a `d` attribute to determine its shape. You can't use `x` and `y` attributes for a path. What you can do is to add a translate transform to the path, e.g:

`<path class="close-x" transform="translate(10, 20)" d="M 140,12 L 150,25 M 150,12 L 140,25"></path>`

So use JS to find the attributes of the text element (might be best to give it an id) and use these for the transform.

```js
var textEl = document.getElementsByTagName('text')[0];
var pathEl = document.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];

var x = parseFloat(textEl.getAttribute('x')) - 8;
var y = parseFloat(textEl.getAttribute('y')) - 29;

pathEl.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + 
x + " " + y + ")");
```

```css
.close-x {
  stroke: black;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

rect {
  fill: #FEFECE;
  stroke: #A80036;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="f491e1k" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"></feGaussianBlur><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"></feColorMatrix><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"></feOffset><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"></feBlend></filter></defs>
<g id="messageBox" >
<!--entity cadvisor-->
<rect filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" width="97" x="100" y="0"></rect>
<rect height="10" width="15" x="177" y="5"></rect>
<rect height="2" width="4" x="175" y="7"></rect>
<rect height="2" width="4" x="175" y="11"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="115" y="33.3027">cadvisor</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 0,0 l10,13 M 10,0 l-10 13"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Notice that the cross starts at (0, 0) but is moved to where the text is.

Comment: I see the general idea but it won't be dynamic right ? because how can I know the units to put in `translate(n,nn)`  with the `<tex---` object ?

Comment: (if you know how to add a cross with a tag like `<cross ...>` I'd love to know it too)

Comment: There is no cross tag, using the `path` tag is the correct approach. To make it dynamic just use JS to change the transform attribute. You don't need to change the values in the `text` element

Comment: yes I understood that I need to change in `transform` and not in `text` but how can I know which value I should put in the `transform`  ?

Comment: That depends on where you want to move it to. What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want to dynamically add the `<path...` tag next to the `text` tag for each container that I have ( so the sentence would be `to put a <path> tag next to each < text> tag` )

Comment: I've updated my code so the menu moves to where you click. But it sounds like what you want is different. If you want to add the cross so it's relative to the `text` element, then use JS to find the `text` element, find its `x` and `y` and then use them for the transform (which you'd put only on the path). But I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. If the text attributes are hard coded, then you can hard code the cross. If they are added dynamically then change the cross transform at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145620/discussion-between-jerome-and-peter-collingridge).